# Count consecutive same numbers in a Dataframe

Tags: python, python-3.x

I'm trying to count the consecutive same values in this Dataframe below:

[image: Dataframe]

DF:

```
{'obligacion': {0: 200000000123,  1: 200000000123,  2: 200000000123,  3: 200000000123,  4: 00000000123,  5: 200000000123,  6: 200000000123,  7: 200000000123,  8: 200000000123,  9: 200000000123,  0: 200000000123,  11: 200000000123,  12: 200000000123,  13: 200000000123,  14: 200000000123,  15: 00000000123,  16: 200000000123,  17: 200000000123}, 0: {0: 'mora18',  1: 'mora17',  2: 'mora16',  3: mora15',  4: 'mora14',  5: 'mora13',  6: 'mora12',  7: 'mora11',  8: 'mora10',  9: 'mora9',  10: 'mora8',  1: 'mora7',  12: 'mora6',  13: 'mora5',  14: 'mora4',  15: 'mora3',  16: 'mora2',  17: 'mora1'}, dias_mora': {0: '-1',  1: '-1',  2: '-1',  3: '-1',  4: '-1',  5: '-1',  6: '-1',  7: '4',  8: '6',  9: 0',  10: '8',  11: '9',  12: '7',  13: '10',  14: '3',  15: '2',  16: '3',  17: '2'}}
```

So I want as the output something like this:

[200000000123: (-1, 7),
(4, 1),
(6, 1),
(0, 1),
(8, 1),
(9, 1),
(7, 1),
(10, 1),
(3, 1),
(2, 1),
(3, 1),
(2, 1)]

The ID number followed by the consecutive count of the numbers, example:

**The number -1 repeats 7 consecutive times**

---------------UPDATE------------------

CODE USED

```
import pandas as pd 
data = {
 'obligacion': [200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123] +
               [200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444],
 '0': [ 'mora18', 'mora17', 'mora16', 'mora15', 'mora14', 'mora13', 'mora12', 'mora11', 'mora10', 'mora9', 'mora8', 'mora7', 'mora6', 'mora5', 'mora4', 'mora3', 'mora2', 'mora1'] +
      [ 'kiwi18', 'kiwi17', 'kiwi16', 'kiwi15', 'kiwi14', 'kiwi13', 'kiwi12', 'kiwi11', 'kiwi10', 'kiwi9', 'kiwi8', 'kiwi7', 'kiwi6', 'kiwi5', 'kiwi4', 'kiwi3', 'kiwi2', 'kiwi1'], 
 'dias_mora': [ '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '4', '6', '0', '8', '9', '7', '10', '3', '2', '3', '2'] +
              [ '12', '0', '4', '4', '4', '7', '10', '4', '-6', '-7', '8', '8', '17', '10', '10', '-2', '3', '2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)  # convert dictionary to dataframe

dict_count = {}
for nid in df.obligacion.unique():
    vector_mora = df['dias_mora'][df.obligacion == nid].values
    groups = groupby(vector_mora)
    result = [(label, sum(1 for _ in group)) for label, group in groups] 
    dict_count[nid] = result
dict_count
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I couldn't find a clever way to do it with just pandas, so a list and loops were needed.

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
     'obligacion': [200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123] +
                   [200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444],
     '0': [ 'mora18', 'mora17', 'mora16', 'mora15', 'mora14', 'mora13', 'mora12', 'mora11', 'mora10', 'mora9', 'mora8', 'mora7', 'mora6', 'mora5', 'mora4', 'mora3', 'mora2', 'mora1'] +
          [ 'kiwi18', 'kiwi17', 'kiwi16', 'kiwi15', 'kiwi14', 'kiwi13', 'kiwi12', 'kiwi11', 'kiwi10', 'kiwi9', 'kiwi8', 'kiwi7', 'kiwi6', 'kiwi5', 'kiwi4', 'kiwi3', 'kiwi2', 'kiwi1'], 
     'dias_mora': [ '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '4', '6', '0', '8', '9', '7', '10', '3', '2', '3', '2'] +
                  [ '12', '0', '4', '4', '4', '7', '10', '4', '-6', '-7', '8', '8', '17', '10', '10', '-2', '3', '2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)  # convert dictionary to dataframe
lob = df['obligacion'].unique().tolist()   # distinct list of first columne
ddall = {}
for o in lob:  # each ob
    ldm = df[df['obligacion']==o]['dias_mora'].tolist()  # filter by ob, convert last column to list

    all = []
    cnt = 0
    for i in range(len(ldm)-1): # each element in list
       cnt += 1
       if ldm[i] != ldm[i+1]:   # if last element in this sequence
          all.append((ldm[i],cnt))  # append tuple to final list
          cnt = 0
    else:
       all.append((ldm[i+1],cnt+1))  # last element
    ddall[o] = [(int(e[0]),e[1]) for e in list(all)]

print(ddall)
```

Output

```
{
  200000000123: [(-1, 7), (4, 1), (6, 1), (0, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1), (7, 1), (10, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1)], 
  200000000444: [(12, 1), (0, 1), (4, 3), (7, 1), (10, 1), (4, 1), (-6, 1), (-7, 1), (8, 2), (17, 1), (10, 2), (-2, 1), (3, 1), (2, 1)]
}
```

---- Update ----

According to the Pandas documentation, iterating over a dataframe should be avoided as it is very slow. To speed up this script, I converted the key columns to lists, zipped them and iterated over the zip object. The script runs about twice as fast. The output is the same.

Here is the faster script:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
     'obligacion': [200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123] +
                   [200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444],
     '0': [ 'mora18', 'mora17', 'mora16', 'mora15', 'mora14', 'mora13', 'mora12', 'mora11', 'mora10', 'mora9', 'mora8', 'mora7', 'mora6', 'mora5', 'mora4', 'mora3', 'mora2', 'mora1'] +
          [ 'kiwi18', 'kiwi17', 'kiwi16', 'kiwi15', 'kiwi14', 'kiwi13', 'kiwi12', 'kiwi11', 'kiwi10', 'kiwi9', 'kiwi8', 'kiwi7', 'kiwi6', 'kiwi5', 'kiwi4', 'kiwi3', 'kiwi2', 'kiwi1'], 
     'dias_mora': [ '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '4', '6', '0', '8', '9', '7', '10', '3', '2', '3', '2'] +
                  [ '12', '0', '4', '4', '4', '7', '10', '4', '-6', '-7', '8', '8', '17', '10', '10', '-2', '3', '2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)  # convert dictionary to dataframe

# convert key columns to lists for faster scan
lstob = df['obligacion'].to_list()
lstdm = df['dias_mora'].to_list()

ddall = {}
lastob = "___"  # will delete this entry
lst = []
lastv = cnt = 1
tt = zip(lstob, lstdm)  # combine lists for iteration
for t in tt:  # each ob/dm
   if t[0] != lastob:  # new ob
      lst.append((int(lastv), cnt)) # add last sequence
      ddall[lastob] = lst  # add list to dictionary
      lastob = t[0]
      lst = []
      lastv = t[1]
      cnt = 1
   else:  # same ob
      if t[1] != lastv: # if new dm
         lst.append((int(lastv), cnt))
         lastv = t[1]
         cnt = 1
      else:
         cnt += 1 # just increment ctr
else: # last row in dataset
   lst.append((int(t[1]), cnt))
   ddall[lastob] = lst

del ddall['___']  # remove temporary entry
print(ddall)
```

---- Update #2 ----

If you want to add dias_mora in the output, you can collect the dm entries as you're counting the values.

For that, here is the updated code:

```
import pandas as pd

data = {
     'obligacion': [200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123, 200000000123] +
                   [200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444, 200000000444],
     '0': [ 'mora18', 'mora17', 'mora16', 'mora15', 'mora14', 'mora13', 'mora12', 'mora11', 'mora10', 'mora9', 'mora8', 'mora7', 'mora6', 'mora5', 'mora4', 'mora3', 'mora2', 'mora1'] +
          [ 'kiwi18', 'kiwi17', 'kiwi16', 'kiwi15', 'kiwi14', 'kiwi13', 'kiwi12', 'kiwi11', 'kiwi10', 'kiwi9', 'kiwi8', 'kiwi7', 'kiwi6', 'kiwi5', 'kiwi4', 'kiwi3', 'kiwi2', 'kiwi1'], 
     'dias_mora': [ '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '-1', '4', '6', '0', '8', '9', '7', '10', '3', '2', '3', '2'] +
                  [ '12', '0', '4', '4', '4', '7', '10', '4', '-6', '-7', '8', '8', '17', '10', '10', '-2', '3', '2']
}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)  # convert dictionary to dataframe

# convert key columns to lists for faster scan
lstob = df['obligacion'].to_list()
lst0  = df['0'].to_list()
lstdm = df['dias_mora'].to_list()

cur0 = ""

ddall = {}
lastob = "___"  # will delete this entry
lst = []
lastv = cnt = 1
tt = zip(lstob, lst0, lstdm)  # combine lists for iteration
for t in tt:  # each ob/dm
   if t[0] != lastob:  # new ob
      lst.append((int(lastv), cnt, cur0)) # add last sequence
      ddall[lastob] = lst  # add list to dictionary
      lastob = t[0]
      lst = []
      lastv = t[2]
      cur0 = t[1]
      cnt = 1
   else:  # same ob
      if t[2] != lastv: # if new dm
         lst.append((int(lastv), cnt, cur0))
         lastv = t[2]
         cur0 = t[1]
         cnt = 1
      else:
         cnt += 1 # just increment ctr
         cur0 += ',' + t[1]
else: # last row in dataset
   lst.append((int(t[2]), cnt, cur0))
   ddall[lastob] = lst

del ddall['___']  # remove temporary entry
print(ddall)
```

Output (formatted)

```
{
200000000123: [
    (-1, 7, 'mora18,mora17,mora16,mora15,mora14,mora13,mora12'), 
    (4,  1, 'mora11'), 
    (6,  1, 'mora10'), 
    (0,  1, 'mora9'), 
    (8,  1, 'mora8'), 
    (9,  1, 'mora7'), 
    (7,  1, 'mora6'), 
    (10, 1, 'mora5'), 
    (3,  1, 'mora4'), 
    (2,  1, 'mora3'), 
    (3,  1, 'mora2'), 
    (2,  1, 'mora1')], 
200000000444: [
    (12, 1, 'kiwi18'), 
    (0,  1, 'kiwi17'), 
    (4,  3, 'kiwi16,kiwi15,kiwi14'), 
    (7,  1, 'kiwi13'), 
    (10, 1, 'kiwi12'), 
    (4,  1, 'kiwi11'), 
    (-6, 1, 'kiwi10'), 
    (-7, 1, 'kiwi9'), 
    (8,  2, 'kiwi8,kiwi7'), 
    (17, 1, 'kiwi6'), 
    (10, 2, 'kiwi5,kiwi4'), 
    (-2, 1, 'kiwi3'), 
    (3,  1, 'kiwi2'), 
    (2,  1, 'kiwi1')]
}
```

The dm list can can be converted to a list using the string `split` method if needed.

Comment: And what if the value of the first column changes over rows, i mean, that data is just the first 18 rows, of a 5000+ rows

Comment: it works, slow, but it works as expected, if there is any way to skip the for's I would appreciate it.

Comment: Awesome, works much faster, I updated the post with my own code, Maybe you want to see the way I did the count. I'm having trouble ordering the result so that the number that is repeated the most times is in the first position

Comment: Is there a way to add column 0 to the tuple ?, so that it saves the first data that it finds for each number. For example 200000000123: [(-1, 7, 'mora18'), (4, 1, 'mora17') ..........]. I can open a new question if necessary.

Answer (score 0):

You could try this approach.

```
data = {'obligacion':
    { 0: 200000000123,  1: 200000000123,
      2: 200000000123,  3: 200000000123,
      4: 200000000123,  5: 200000000123,
      6: 200000000123,  7: 200000000123,
      8: 200000000123,  9: 200000000123,
     10: 200000000456, 11: 200000000456,
     12: 200000000456, 13: 200000000456,
     14: 200000000456, 15: 200000000456,
     16: 200000000456, 17: 200000000456},
    0:
    { 0: 'mora18', 1: 'mora17',
      2: 'mora16', 3: 'mora15',
      4: 'mora14', 5: 'mora13',
      6: 'mora12', 7: 'mora11',
      8: 'mora10', 9:  'mora9',
     10: 'mora8', 11:  'mora7',
     12: 'mora6', 13: 'mora5',
     14: 'mora4', 15: 'mora3',
     16: 'mora2', 17: 'mora1'},
    'dias_mora':
    { 0: '-1',  1: '0',
      2: '-1',  3: '6',
      4: '-1',  5: '4',
      6: '-1',  7: '4',
      8:  '6',  9: '0',
     10:  '8', 11: '9',
     12:  '7', 13: '10',
     14:  '3', 15: '2',
     16:  '3', 17: '2'}}

df = pd.DataFrame.from_dict(data)  # convert dictionary to dataframe

from collections import defaultdict
d_new = defaultdict(list) #setup a dictionary that can contain lists

#use a crosstab function to count the values for each obligacion
ctab = pd.crosstab(index=df['dias_mora'], columns=df['obligacion'])

#for each  obligacion, get the dias_mora key and counts
for obl,d_m in ctab.items():
    #for each dias_mora key, check if count is > 0. If so, write to dict
    for d_m_key,count_dm in d_m.items():
        if count_dm > 0: d_new[obl].append((d_m_key,count_dm))

#convert defaultdict to normal dict
d_new = dict(d_new)

print (d_new)
```

The output for this will be as follows:

```
{200000000123: [('-1', 4), ('0', 2), ('4', 2), ('6', 2)], 200000000456: [('10', 1), ('2', 2), ('3', 2), ('7', 1), ('8', 1), ('9', 1)]}
```

If you want to convert the keys in the tuple to numbers, then you can change them while pushing it into the list.

```
if count_dm > 0: d_new[obl].append((int(d_m_key),count_dm))
```

This will give you a result as follows:

```
{200000000123: [(-1, 4), (0, 2), (4, 2), (6, 2)], 200000000456: [(10, 1), (2, 2), (3, 2), (7, 1), (8, 1), (9, 1)]}
```

Comment: The program should count the same numbers that are repeated consecutively, not the total amount, it was difficult to explain that part